# pycryptodomex install oserror

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am trying to install pycryptodomex and pycrypto on my Linux Ubuntu 64bits machines. However, I kept getting this error: (Thanks in advance!)

```
haomin@haomin-R110CS:~$ pip install pycryptodomex
Collecting pycryptodomex
Installing collected packages: pycryptodomex

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)

File "/home/haomin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycryptodomex-3.4.3.dist-info'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo` or using root account for installation.